# Project with multiple MapSeries - script to select specific series and range

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, map-series

Currently working a project that contains 9 map series with over 22,000 pages total - split across datum and scale. Want to script a solution that allows us to export pages as individual PDFs by selecting a specific series and range - ultimately to allow us to have multiple PC's exporting maps at once.

All the examples on the ArcGIS Pro help appear to be referencing projects with a single Map Series so I'm a bit stuck how to approach. So far I've written a small script to check for the presence of the series and return the page count:

```
    print("Layouts:")
    for lyt in aprx.listLayouts():
    print(lyt.name)
    ms = lyt.mapSeries
    if ms is None:
            print('\t'+"None available")
    else:
        if ms is not None:
            print('\t'+"Page count:",ms.pageCount)
```

I can export a PDF based off a selection on the index layer - however the problem I am finding is I don't know which map series the selection is operating on. Anyone have to suggestions to specify which map series? Would ideally prefer to go with ranges than selecting attributes (ie 1 - 500, 501 - 1000 etc)

```
#make a selection based off index feature
if not lyt.mapSeries is None:
    ms = lyt.mapSeries
    if ms.enabled:
        ms = lyt.mapSeries
        indexLyr = ms.indexLayer
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(indexLyr, "NEW_SELECTION", "ZONE = '56'")
        ms.exportToPDF(Output + "\\TEST.pdf", "SELECTED")
```

Answer (score 1):

A layout can only contain a single MapSeries object.

Consequently, to support multiple map series in a single project you will need to have multiple layouts (each with one map series enabled).

You can then use ListLayouts with an index to create Layout objects from them.